# In ubuntu 15.04 title bar is not showing title

Tags: 15.04, titlebar

After 15.04 installation I can no longer see the title bar title when a window is maximised.
It worked perfectly in 14.04 but now it's messed up.

This is how I see my eclipse not maximised:

[image]

And this is what happens when it's maximised

[image]

In 14.04 "MainStream" were visible on the title bar with maximised window.
This happens also with other programs/windows.

Thanks

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134172/window-title-bars-missing-occasionally-in-unity)

Comment: that question is too old to work and the problem is slightly different

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the title bar and menu bar reside in the same space.

When your cursor is not at the title (for example,ready to select some option), the title is displayed.

Comment: no, the title is never displayed.

Comment: The title is displayed only when another window is opened on top as you can see below. The title is grey but it's visible in the background.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/SLTX0.png


P.S. I cant directly post images because of my low rep

Comment: wonder how we can enable a private chat so that i can walk through a solution with you.

Comment: @nyxee He (and you for that matter) need a minimum of 20 rep to be allowed to chat.

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall the desktop via

`apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity compizconfig-settings-manager`

If that does not clear your problem, you could delete dconf via :

```
cd ~ ; mkdir .config/dconf.ORIG
mv .config/dconf/ .config/dconf.ORIG/
```

You risk losing a few personal settings like font settings, but you may return to a sane and better desktop.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing this. I'm sure there are better solutions than reinstalling the desktop (which can take a long time & mess things up), especially since this is such a minor issue. I *definitely* would suggest against entirely removing dconf.

Comment: OK.  But, your solution is more than welcome. Reinstalling the desktop was extremely quick on my low end laptop.

Comment: I don't have a solution of my own, I was just putting that comment there as a heads up for the OP that I would wait for other solutions before doing something like this. If nothing else is left then I would say it's fine.

Comment: I tried with the less invasive solution, I moved the dconf folder but the problem is still here. My 15.04 installation is a fresh one, I didn't update the system.