# Ubuntu 16.04 Unity Panel Problem: Window Title Not Shown

Tags: 16.04, unity, window, panel, appmenu

When the application is maximized, the title of window is sometimes shown on the panel bar. This is OK.

[image: Title shown in panel correctly]

And when the window is inactive (switched to another application), the title of first window is blurred (grayed out) as expected. That is also working as expected.

[image: Title is grayed out in panel]

**But** when the application is focused again, **the title of the active window is not shown in the top panel bar**.

[image: Title is not shown in panel]

I am using 2 monitors and there are a lot of applications running at the same time, so switching back and forth applications/windows is a common thing. And unfortunately the missing title bar of the active window is misleading and distracting.

The problem was also present in 15.04. See similar questions; " [In ubuntu 15.04 title bar is not showing title](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672428/in-ubuntu-15-04-title-bar-is-not-showing-title) " and " [How to bring the title bar on maximize of an app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781780/how-to-bring-the-title-bar-on-maximize-of-an-app) ".

Answer (score 7):

This is some kind of temporary fix I've found. 
Go to "System settings -> Appearance -> Behavior" and there in "Menus visibility" section check the option "Displayed on mouse hovering". The menus then will load only on mouse hover, and the titles will be shown.

Comment: I was having this same problem with 16.10 and this fix worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me but in reverse.

I uninstalled the global menu components via `sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu`. I then had the problem described above when my windows where in full screen mode.  By checking "Displayed in the menu bar" and "Displayed on mouse hovering" in "System settings -> Appearance -> Behavior" my tile bar information is now displayed in the panel UNTIL I mouse hover over the panel while the application is in full screen mode. The title bar info disappears when hovering over with the mouse. I don't know why it does this but it works fine for me.  Better actually since the info is present all the time so long as I avoid hovering over the panel which is not too hard.  Thanks *Илиан Д. Иванов*.