# How to display window titles on not maximized windows?

Tags: unity, window, titlebar

I recently moved from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS with all the resulting software upgrades. There have been a number of UI changes, but this one is most annoying.

Windows that are not maximized do not show the window name/title anywhere.
The menu bar does not evens display the application name; it's just "Text Editor" for gedit or "Files" for nautilus.
The title bar just sits empty.

This is very inconvenient for many reasons; for instance, if you have multiple (untabbed) instances of gedit open it's hard to tell which file is open where.
Titles *are* shown for the currently selected window in the application switcher, but that's little consolation.

How can I get window titles back to *title* bars?

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Unity 7.4.0.

Comment: Hmm, this is odd, because I'm running 16.04 and the titles still are in the title bar.  Just on a penchant, try going to `System Settings` > `Appearance` > `Restore Behaviour Settings`.

Comment: @anonymous2 No effect. (I guess I *may* have copied over settings from one of my 14.04 settings files when migrating; couldn't say now.)

Answer (score 1):

I've a suggestion see my comment in this thread: https://askubuntu.com/a/798471/568202

> This is some kind of temporary fix I've found. Go to "System settings -> Appearance -> Behavior" and there in "Menus visibility" section check the option "Displayed on mouse hovering". The menus then will load only on mouse hover, and the titles will be shown.

I think it's related with the show/hide behavior of the menus and the titles (when you focus on menu the title disappears). Basically the temporary fix is to activate the show on mouse hover option for menus. I hope it helps a bit to ease the situation until the strange behavior is dealed with by ubuntu/unity developers.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Provide at least essential steps that describe the solution

Comment: I have this setting enabled already.

Comment: Works for me in 16.04, but I'd like the menu to be displayed at all times too.