# Ubuntu 14.04 title bar is absent and there is no option to go back

Tags: 14.04

I opened my PC and found that there was no title bar available. I do not know what happened but I am not able to operate my PC. Also, shut off button is not available. My PC's shut down button is also not working. I could not do anything because the close icon was not also present.

Comment: I do not see any picture… Can you open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)? If yes, you should be able to use the `poweroff` or `reboot` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You should install CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) by typing this command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

open it, and under *effects* category, enable *windows decorations*.

[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134172/window-title-bars-missing-occasionally-in-unity) is a similar question, you can find more ways to solve this if above doesn't work.